# Javascript: - Refresh a page with a different time of refresh depending which page anchor they are viewing

Tags: refresh

I have this refresh script that refresh the page every 30 seconds.

```
<script>
 var time = new Date().getTime();
  $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
   time = new Date().getTime();
  });

 function refresh() {
  if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 30000)
   window.location.reload(true);
    else 
   setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
  }

 setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
</script>
```

Is it possible to set a different time of page refresh depending on the page anchor the user is viewing?

If user is viewing the default anchor page.php#main then the page will refresh every 30 seconds.  But if the user is viewing  anchor page  #view1, then the page refresh is set to 60 seconds.  Then on refresh returns the page to page.php#view1

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  I found an answer to my problem.

Using the window.name attribute I was able to set a value in seconds in the window.name and then a small javascript in each anchor area of the page which changed the window.name value when I needed a different time for refresh.  I setup different values in the javascript function as follows.

```
function refresh() {
 var secs;
  if (window.name == '1'){
   secs = '60000';
    } else if (window.name == '2') {
   secs = '120000';
    } else if (window.name == '3'){
   secs = '0';
    } else {
   secs = '180000'
    }
     
if((new Date().getTime() - time >= secs)&&(secs != '0'))
 window.location.reload(true);
```

Then in the html where the anchors are I added following scripts where I needed different times for refresh.  I used a paragraph tag to help get it working.

```
<p id='demo'></p>
                    
<script>
 window.name = '1';
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = window.name;
</script>

<script>
 window.name = '2';
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = window.name;
</script>
```